# CareerStack - An Android app to search Stack Overflow Careers from your mobile or tablet

Tags: app, android, java

## Screenshots

[image]  [image]  [image]

[image]

### About

Powered by Stack Overflow Careers' RSS feed, CareerStack is an Android app to search & share job listings easily from any Android device.

Users can search by:

- Keywords or skills
- Location - City, Country, Zip
- Distance (10 - 500 miles/km from location)
- Remote work
- Relocation offered

Additionally, users can open, copy and share links for full listings.

The app is localized in:

- English
- Dutch
- French
- German
- Spanish

### License

Originally closed source, I opened it under the Apache License v2.

### Download

You can find CareerStack on any Android device here:

https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.ovrhere.android.careerstack

[image: Find 'CareerStack' on Google Play]

### Platform

Android 2.3.3 & up, Tablets & Mobile

### Contact

Feedback is greatly appreciated and can be left here or on the store description.

### Code

CareerStack is written in Java using Android SDK. Uses support libraries and external library for preferences.
Source and issue tracking can be found at: https://bitbucket.org/iamovrhere/careerstack/